# Current page state for html image button

Tags: html, css, image, button

I have a site where I want the header buttons (which are images) to have a normal state, rollover state, and a current page state, where when that page is viewed, the header button displays a different image than normal. I should note this website draws from a database with php.

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="header" id="header1">
        <a href='index.php?Program=BIT' class="header_bit" id="header_bit" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFF">
        <img alt="Photonics & Laser Technology" 
        src="+images/_header_all/bit_normal_v2.png" 
        onmouseover="this.src='+images/_header_all/bit_hover_v2.png'" 
        onmouseout="this.src='+images/_header_all/bit_normal_v2.png'" 
        width="180px" height="250px"/>
        </a>
        <a href='index.php?Program=IMD' class="header_imd" id="header_imd" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFF">
        <img alt="Interactive Multimedia & Design" 
        src="+images/_header_all/imd_normal_v2.png" 
        onmouseover="this.src='+images/_header_all/imd_hover_v2.png'" 
        onmouseout="this.src='+images/_header_all/imd_normal_v2.png'" 
        width="180px" height="250px"/>
        </a>
        <a href='index.php?Program=NET' class="header_net" id="header_net" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFF">
        <img alt="Networking Technology" 
        src="+images/_header_all/net_normal_v2.png" 
        onmouseover="this.src='+images/_header_all/net_hover_v2.png'" 
        onmouseout="this.src='+images/_header_all/net_normal_v2.png'" 
        width="180px" height="250px"/>
        </a>   
        <a href='index.php?Program=PLT' class="header_plt" id="header_plt" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFF">
        <img alt="Photonics & Laser Technology" 
        src="+images/_header_all/plt_normal_v2.png" 
        onmouseover="this.src='+images/_header_all/plt_hover_v2.png'" 
        onmouseout="this.src='+images/_header_all/plt_normal_v2.png'" 
        width="180px" height="250px"/>
        </a>  
        <a href='index.php?Program=IRM' class="header_irm" id="header_irm" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFF">
        <img alt="Information Research Technology" 
        src="+images/_header_all/irm_normal_v2.png"
        onmouseover="this.src='+images/_header_all/irm_hover_v2.png'" 
        onmouseout="this.src='+images/_header_all/irm_normal_v2.png'"  
        width="180px" height="250px"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
/*Program header items*/
#header_bit{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:20px;
    }
/*#header_bit:active img{
    background-image:url(+images/_header_all/imd_hover_v2.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }*/
#header_imd{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:20px;
    }
#header_net{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:20px;
    }
#header_plt{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:20px;

    }
#header_irm{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:20px;
    }
```

I'm at a loss, all methods I've found no not apply or don't work. Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: Can you build a relationship between the <a> link state and the image?I'm thinking that you could use a:visited img    selector (If link has been clicked, then target the child image and change the style. I'm not sure if it will work though

Comment: I'm also wondering if not using an image tag vs using the css background image property would be of better use here so you could flip between background images based on state such as :hover, :visited, and normal.